# Use curl to grab data from more than 30 different links using loop

Tags: php, loops, curl

I am writing a php script to grab information from more than 30 different links currently.

Say I have an array storing all the links, and then use a `foreach` loop to pass the link to a function `grabDataFromLink($url)`

But turns out it can at most grab 10 to 15 links' data, and then it stopped giving data anymore. Why is it so?

My code is something like this:

```
function grabDataFromLink($link){
  $ch = curl_init($link);   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC); 
  $content = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $content;
  curl_close($ch);
}

foreach ($links as $key => $link)
   grabDataFromLink($link);
```

Comment: no, no error was shown at all ( i used curl_error to check )

Comment: Maybe some security from the domain you are retrieving the links from? Perhaps your requests are to fast and some detection kicks in?

Comment: Check the php error log, check if a time limit or memory limit occurred. Is so, put `set_time_limit(0);ini_set(memory_limit, -1);` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: after setting the time limit and memor_limit, i can curl all data now, thx :)

Comment: Please write an answer and accept it so that this question is removed from the unsolved questions list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the php error log, check if a time limit or memory limit occurred. Is so, put set_time_limit(0);ini_set(memory_limit, -1); at the beginning of your script.
(answered by xdazz)